# I want to create an observer <sales_order_place_after>

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, invoice

I'm trying to write an observer `<sales_order_place_after>` that create invoice automatically when an order is placed. Please tell me how to do it.

Comment: have look at http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-orders/automatically-invoice-ship-complete-order-in-magento/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **custom Magento module** will be required for **this task**

> Let’s name it   **Karthik_Orderhook**

**Step 1:-** First, create a module initializer in 
`/app/etc/modules/Karthik_Orderhook.xml` with the following content:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Karthik_Orderhook>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Karthik_Orderhook>
    </modules>
</config>
```

---

**Step 2:-** Create a **module configuration file** config.xml in `app/code/local/NAMESPACE/MODULENAME/etc/` (replace NAMESPACE and MODULENAME with your own values). In our case the path will be `/app/code/local/Karthik/Orderhook/etc/config.xml` with content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Karthik_Orderhook>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </Karthik_Orderhook>
    </modules>

    <global>

        <models>            
            <orderhook>
                <class>Karthik_Orderhook</class>
            </orderhook>
        </models>

        <events>
            <sales_order_place_after>
                <observers>
                    <auto_invoice_order>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Karthik_Orderhook_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>implementOrderStatus</method>
                    </auto_invoice_order>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_place_after>
        </events>

    </global>
</config>
```

I assume you know the working of config.xml and above mentioned tags

**Step 3:-** Create observer file app/code/community/Karthik/Orderhook/Model/Observer.php with the following content:

```
   <?php

class Karthik_Orderhook_Model_Observer 
{
    public function implementOrderStatus($event)
    {
        $order = $event->getOrder();

        if ($this->_getPaymentMethod($order) == 'ccsave') {
            if ($order->canInvoice())
                $this->_processOrderStatus($order);
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

As we have described below – order status will be changed only if “Credit Card Save” payment method has been used with the order. If you don’t need these conditions – just remove the below function **_getPaymentMethod**.

```
private function _getPaymentMethod($order)
    {
        return $order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode();
    }

    private function _processOrderStatus($order)
    {
        $invoice = $order->prepareInvoice();

        $invoice->register();
        Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
           ->addObject($invoice)
           ->addObject($invoice->getOrder())
           ->save();

        $invoice->sendEmail(true, '');
        $this->_changeOrderStatus($order);
        return true;
    }

    private function _changeOrderStatus($order)
    {
        $statusMessage = '';
        $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING, true); //Setting the status or changing the status of the order placed       
    $order->save();
    }
}
```

If You want to change status different from above mentioned on then you can replace the code with any of below mentioned

```
/**
 * change order status to 'Completed'
 */
$order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE, true)->save();
Similarly, you can change the order status to pending, processing, canceled, closed, held, etc.

/**
 * change order status to "Pending"
 */
$order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_NEW, true)->save();

/**
 * change order status to "Pending Paypal"
 */
$order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PENDING_PAYMENT, true)->save();

/**
 * change order status to "Processing"
 */
$order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING, true)->save();

/**
 * change order status to "Completed"
 */
$order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE, true)->save();

/**
 * change order status to "Closed"
 */
$order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CLOSED, true)->save();

/**
 * change order status to "Canceled"
 */
$order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED, true)->save();

/**
 * change order status to "Held"
 */
$order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_HOLDED, true)->save();
```

Comment: Will it work for "cash on delivery" method also? And by changing the order status only will it create the invoice also?

Comment: Yes @AliZaki it will work for cash on delivery" method but you to change the  code from **$this->_getPaymentMethod($order) == 'ccsave'**  to this
**$this->_getPaymentMethod($order) == 'checkmo'** **checkmo** is the code for **check money order**
for **Cash on delivery** use this **cashondelivery**

Comment: It is not working. Order status is not changed neither the invoice is submitted/created.

Comment: can u paste the code you have written @AliZaki

Comment: I have written exactly the same code that you give. I just changed `if ($this->_getPaymentMethod($order) == 'ccsave') {
` **To** ` if ($this->_getPaymentMethod($order) == 'checkmo') {` .

Comment: (http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/153261/get-values-from-database-and-show-them-on-invoice-pdf) Please take a look at on this question of mine. See if you can help me.

Comment: sure i will look into it

Answer (score 1):

You need to create module or modified already created custom module and below xml code to config.xml

```
<events>    
    <sales_order_place_after>
        <observers>
            <test_order_place>
                <class>Namespace_Module_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>Savedata</method>
                <type>singleton</type>
            </test_order_place>
        </observers>
    </sales_order_place_after>
</events>
```

Create Observer.php in Model and place below code and you logic

```
class Namespace_Module_Model_Observer {

    public function Savedata(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        /*some code*/

    }
}
```